# CRM How to Split with Multiple Types of Characters and New Line

Tags: c#, string, split

I'm trying split a string in CRM using different characters (like whitespace, comma, period, colon, semicolon, slash, pipe). But I also need to split on a new line as well.

The below function is working to split using different characters:

```
string[] values = propertylist.Split(new Char[] { ' ', ',', '.', ':','\t', '/', ';', '|', '\\', '\r', '\n'});
```

I read that for new line the symbol must be '\r\n'.. but for some reason if I change the function a little bit from Split(new Char[] to Split(new String[], even after changing to use double quotation mark, I keep getting error "Cannot convert from string[] to char[]..." even though I am already using double quotation mark.

Any suggestions for this is appreciated very much. Thanks!

-elisabeth

Comment: `Chars` are defined in single quotes; `Char c = ','` and `Strings` are defined in double quotes `String s = ","`. Are you defining them properly for `String[]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you changed the code in your question to this:

```
string[] values =
    propertylist.Split(new string[] { " ", ... "\r", "\n"});
```

The problem is that the method overload that accepts a `string[]` requires additional parameters. Without supplying those parameters, you get a syntax error.

This is the closest match for your original code:

```
string[] values =
    propertylist.Split(new string[] { " ", ... "\r\n"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: Doh how could I miss that... this answers my question!! Thanks much :)